# Needed help improving this crawler

Tags: php

I have this crawler, but it will index only the domain root ex: mydomain.com but not /somethingelse.php, /otherpage.html i mean the website internal links...

Is there a way to modify this script to be able to index more pages rather than the root?

```
    <?php
require_once('./pathtoconfig');
require_once('./functions.php')
set_time_limit(500);
error_reporting(-1);    
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8;');

$db = @mysqli_connect($conf['host'], $conf['user'], $conf['pass'], $conf['name']);
mysqli_query($db, 'SET NAMES utf8');

if(!$db) {  
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ") " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

//Insert links separated by commas.

$url = array('mydomain1.com', 'mydomain2.com');                         
foreach($url as $k) {       
    $url = parse_url($k);   
    if(!isset($url['path'])) {
        $selectData = "SELECT * FROM web WHERE url = '$k'";
        if(mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($db, $selectData)) == null) {
            $content = getUrl($k);
            preg_match('#<title>(.*)</title>#i', $content, $title);
            preg_match_all('/<img src=.([^"\' ]+)/', $content, $img);
            preg_match('/<head>.+<meta name="description" content=.([^"\']+)/is', $content, $description);
            preg_match('/<head>.+<meta name="author" content=.([^"\']+)/is', $content, $author);
            #preg_match_all('/href=.([^"\' ]+)/i', $content, $anchor);
            preg_match('/<body.*?>(.*?)<\/body>/is', $content, $body);
            if(!empty($title[1]) AND !empty($description[1]) || !empty($body[1])) {
                echo 'Title: '; @print_r($title[1]);
                echo "\n";  
                $body_trim = trim(preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]+;/i",'',(strip_tags(@$body[0])))); $bodyContent = substr(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $body_trim), 0, 255);

                $description_trim = trim(preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]+;/i",'',(strip_tags(@$description[1])))); $descContent = substr(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$description_trim), 0, 255);

                $bodyContent = str_replace('\'', '', $bodyContent);
                $descContent = str_replace('\'', '', $descContent);
                echo 'Description: '; @print_r($descContent);
                echo "\n";
                echo 'Author: '; @print_r($author[1]);
                echo "\n";
                echo 'URL: '; @print_r($k); $date = date("d M Y");
                echo "\n";
                echo "\n---------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
                $insertData = "INSERT INTO `web` (`url` ,  `title` ,  `description` ,  `body` ,  `author`, `date`) VALUES ('".$k."', '".@$title[1]."', '".@$descContent."', '".@$bodyContent."', '".@$author[1]."', '".$date."')";
                #echo $insertData;
                mysqli_query($db, $insertData);
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Hope you can help me, thanks alot, really appreciate it.

Comment: Have you tried looking for links within the document that you load?

Comment: Yes, it won't load if there exist any extension after the .com

Comment: Where's the code that looks for links within the document?

Comment: The links will go inside the crawler within the array the top document. $url = array('mydomain1.com', 'mydomain2.com');

Comment: Is your problem that it doesn't work if you have a URL like http://stackoverflow.com/q/26730789/50447 in your `$url` array, or that you want your crawler to find links within the document and also follow those?

Comment: Yes my problem is that it won't work if there do exist something like stackoverflow.com/q/26730789/50447 will simply not load, but yes if i will input domain.com to be able to find the internal links by depth too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your crawler doesn't accept URLs with path information, as you explicitly check that there is none:

```
if(!isset($url['path'])) {
```

You could remove this test altogether (along with the matching closing `}`), or change the test to be more appropriate for your needs

Comment: Thank you so much for this highlight it actually now works if i add the links manually but is there a way to make it search deep for the links inside the domain itself?

Comment: To find links in the page, take a look at @rjdown's answer - you'd just need to work on the results of that, in addition to your original seed list - you may also want to filter offsite links, otherwise you could end up downloading a lot more than you want.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regex to parse HTML. Use DomDocument instead. You will easily be able to find all the links then. Here's a function I found with a quick google... you can see how simple this is!

```
/**
 * @author Jay Gilford
 */

/**
 * get_links()
 * 
 * @param string $url
 * @return array
 */
function get_links($url) {

    // Create a new DOM Document to hold our webpage structure
    $xml = new DOMDocument();

    // Load the url's contents into the DOM (the @ supresses any errors from invalid XML)
    @$xml->loadHTMLFile($url);

    // Empty array to hold all links to return
    $links = array();

    //Loop through each <a> and </a> tag in the dom and add it to the link array
    foreach($xml->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
        $links[] = array('url' => $link->getAttribute('href'), 'text' => $link->nodeValue);
    }

    //Return the links
    return $links;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, but the problem is, i don't really have the enough knowledge to re-write the code within the crawler.